# How i push an object on my array with hook on react js?

Tags: reactjs

I wanna push the object "task" on my array todoList.

For the moment only the value task is recorded on my todoList. It's weird because on my const Addtask, the value task is my object.

When i click on my button i also want him to change is value "etat".If i want to sort it, do i need to use .map.sort ?

Did i forget something ?

```
function Task() {
  const [task, setTask] = useState({ task: "", etat: "en cours" });

  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);

  const switchEnCours = () => {
    setTask({etat:"terminé"});
  };

  const deleteTask = () => {
    setTask({etat:"supprimée"});
  };

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    setTask(e.target.value);
  };
  const AddTask = (e) => {
    setTodoList([...todoList, task]);

    console.log(todoList);
  };

  useEffect(() => console.log(todoList), [todoList]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={handleInput}></input>
      <button onClick={AddTask}>Valider</button>
      <div className="DivColonne">
        <div className="Colonne">
          <h1>Tâche à faire</h1>

          {todoList.map((insertTask) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <p>{insertTask.task}</p>
                <button onClick={switchEnCours}>{insertTask.etat}</button>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <div className="Colonne">
          <h1>Tâche en cours</h1>
          {encours === "terminé" ? (
            <div>
              {todoList.map((insert) => {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <p>{insert.task}</p>
                    <button onClick={deleteTask}>{insert.etat}</button>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div></div>
          )}
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Tâches terminées</h1>
          {encours === "supprimée" ? (
            <div>
              <p>{todoList}</p>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div></div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you want to update an object state you need to pass in the old properties of that object that are not going to change, so you dont lose those properties. This is done using a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

for example your

```js
const switchEnCours = () => {
  setTask({ etat: "terminé" });
};
```

should be

```js
const switchEnCours = () => {
  setTask({...task, etat: "terminé"});
};
```

you also have to do the same with the handleInput function

```js
const handleInput = (e) => {
  setTask({...task, task: e.target.value});
};
```

Comment: THANKS but now i have this error Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {task, etat}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: your Todolist is an array of Objects so this line where you have 
`<p>{todoList}</p>` would throw an error

Comment: you have to map through the todo list and render each object property of the individual todo